# Logging a user in with MeteorJS and ReactJS and Facebook

Tags: reactjs, meteor

I used the following package.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-facebook-login

This returns a users information from Facebook successfully on the client side. I can log the user in using this.setUser but it's only logged in for that one communication.

My client side callback is

```
Meteor.call('users.facebookLogin', 
    response.email, response.name, response.picture.data.url, (error, result) => {
      if (result) {
        console.log(result)
        // Redirect user to homepage
      }
    })
```

and my meteor method currently attempts this

```
Meteor.methods({
'users.facebookLogin'(email, name, picture) {
  check(email, String)
  check(name, String)
  check(picture, String)

  let user = Accounts.findUserByEmail(email)

  if(user) {
    this.setUser(user._id)
  }
},
})
```

This logs the user in but if you refresh the browser the user has to log in again. I want the user to be logged in the same way as Meteor.loginWithPassword.

Comment: Have you checked [Meteor.loginWithService](https://docs.meteor.com/api/accounts.html#requestpermissions)? It handles usually everything you need like storing the token, keeping re-login with the token, and session handling for the current user.

Comment: Yes this is correct @Jankapunkt I tried to go about this the wrong way instead a button to fire Meteor.loginWithFacebook() was correct.